# How do I self-reference a DataTemplate in UWP XAML Resources?

Tags: xaml, uwp, datatemplate

I've seen something along these lines done with `{DynamicResource xyz}`on some other SO question, but it doesn't seem to work with UWP. Here's my XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="commentTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="4" Background="#40606060" MinHeight="64">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="4" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Image MaxHeight="96" Source="{Binding Path=Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Background="#18808080" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                <FontIcon Margin="2,0" Glyph="&#xE19D;" />
                <TextBlock Margin="2,0" Text="{Binding Path=Score, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Button Content="Reply" Margin="2,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="48" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Comments}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'd like to self-reference the `DataTemplate` in the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate` property. How would I go about replacing it?

Comment: I am not sure I have the answer but you can try this, replace ItemTemplate="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" with ItemTemplate="{StaticResource commentTemplate}" or with {Binding RelativeSource Mode=Self}. Let me know if it works else I'll try it out. Also if you could provide a spample data a JSON or something so that I can test the code

Comment: I have already tried referencing it by `{StaticResource commentTemplate}` but it seems it doesn't support self-referencing. It always threw an error `Can't find resource ...`. I checked your other solution and it no longer throws an exception. It seems to be working, partially at least. When I add any nested comments it tries to convert the relative binding for some reason: `

Comment: `Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl' to type 'DataTemplate'; BindingExpression: Path='' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemTemplate' (type 'DataTemplate'). 
`

Comment: It seems that `{Binding RelativeSource={Relative Source Mode=Self}}` refers to the itemscontrol instead of the datatemplate as a whole. It's gonna be difficult to figure out an alternative for that. [Here](http://pastebin.com/c7vT91Kz) is the data I use for the `ItemsSource` of the main `ItemsControl`.

Comment: [I almost did it.](http://imgur.com/a/a5CIF) Now it displays the comment but the layout looks weird. Basically, I added `x:Name` attribute to the `DataTemplate` and on the `ItemsControl` I used `{Binding ElementName=commentTemplate}`. It kinda works, but I don't think this is a recommended approach.

Comment: Well yes it is not the recommended approach as each instance of the template would create another instance so it'll create a UI Tree that extends to infinity. but if that's what you need in your case then I guess you could go about it in the way i've told you with the binding. About the UI looking wierd I'll make a test case on my side and check it out

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that may work for you.  I use this in our POS application - although this is my first attempt at nesting it.  The xaml designer complains because of the selector StaticResource reference prior to its declaration, but it works at runtime.

Essentially, I use this to select a different data template based on the class that is bound to the item.  In this case, there is only one type, so really we are just using the class type to decide what template to use.

MyModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public List<MyModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

MyTemplateSelector:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MyModelTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        if (item is MyModel)
        {
            return MyModelTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }
}
```

My MainPage:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App7.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App7"
    xmlns:models="using:App7.Models"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="myModelTemplate" x:DataType="models:MyModel">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Desc, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=Children, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="selector" MyModelTemplate="{StaticResource myModelTemplate}" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView x:Name="lstView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" >

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<MyModel> lst { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        BuildList();
        lstView.ItemsSource = lst;
    }

    private void BuildList()
    {
        lst = new List<MyModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyModel mod = new MyModel();
            mod.Id = i;
            mod.Desc = "Desc" + i.ToString();
            mod.Children = new List<MyModel>();

            for (int j = 100; j < 102; j++)
            {
                MyModel mod2 = new MyModel();
                mod2.Id = j;
                mod2.Desc = "Desc" + j.ToString();
                mod2.Children = new List<MyModel>();
                for (int k = 1000; k < 1002; k++)
                {
                    MyModel mod3 = new MyModel();
                    mod3.Id = k;
                    mod3.Desc = "Desc" + k.ToString();
                    mod3.Children = new List<MyModel>();
                    mod2.Children.Add(mod3);
                }
                mod.Children.Add(mod2);
            }
            lst.Add(mod);
        }
    }
}
```